# How to call a function in a Web API using Postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have a function that checks whether a user already exists by looking through the database to see if the email registered has already been used. The function accepts the email address as a parameter, and can be seen below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UserExists")]
        private bool UserExists(string EmailAddress)
        {
            using var db = new NorthwindContext();
            var user = db.UserLogin.Where(zz => zz.EmailAddress == EmailAddress).FirstOrDefault();

            return user != null;
        }
    }
```

Now, using PostMan I am trying to pass an email address to check what the function returns, if my understanding is correct, it should be either true or false, considering the function is of type bool.

However, PostMan indicates that the requested resource cannot be found:

[image: Postman 404 Error]

My Startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace INF354ReportHomework
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                }));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass it in the querystring?

Comment: Did you mean to make it `private`?

Comment: Please add your Startup file in Question

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest using `return db.UserLogin.Any(zz => zz.EmailAddress == EmailAddress);`

Comment: I second the `private` issue and have you tried `[FromBody] string EmailAddress` ?

Comment: Instead of string EmailAddress try making a class and using that class inside the function.
public class User{ public string EmailAddress {get;set;} }

Comment: @NimaTalebi I have added the startup file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change UserExists method from private to public,
controllers methods should be public.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you to everyone who mentioned the fact that it had been private and not public. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameters to your request like this:
[image]

You should also change protection lvl of your method from private to public.